# NullReferenceException in TCPClient when connecting to the server in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, nullreferenceexception

I am testing some tcp ip based server by my test client under .net in c#.

My test client class is some trivial async socket code:

```
public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            _tcpClient.BeginConnect(IPAddress, Port, OnConnectCallBack, null);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, exc.Message);
        }
    }

private void OnConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            _tcpClient.EndConnect(ar);

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Connection error: " + exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

_tcpClient is a TcpClient instance.

I try to make several (100) connections to the server at a time to stress test it. If I add some 50 msec sleep between calling connect, it works like a charm. But, when I try to connect in a foreach(...) iteration without adding sleep between connections, OnConnectCallBack throws the exception: *A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.dll. Connection error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* Sometimes I get *target machine refuse the connection* exception.

After setting a breakpoint, I noticed it comes from _tcpClient: none of its methods and property values can be seen, all of them has null reference exception value, and its Client property is null.

at TestClient.OnConnectCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)  C:...\TestClient.cs(82)
    at LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
    at ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
    at ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
    at RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
    at ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
    at ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
    at ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
    at LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
    at LazyAsyncResult.InvokeCallback(Object result)
    at QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
    at ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
    at _ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: If you have no delay, is it possible that the `TcpClient` is busy in the `BusyConnect()` preventing the re-entrancy? The target machine error may be a result of the server not having enough queue slots waiting in the listen().

Comment: Hi Pekka! Thx! What do you mean as 'BusyConnect()'?

Comment: Sorry. I meant `BeginConnect()`. Since the operation is asynchronous, it is possible that it is not safe to recall the method under all circumstances. You don't explain whether you are trying to stress test of functionally check the server. If it is the first, you could use separate instances of the `TcpClient` for each connection.

Comment: The reason is: to make stress test, exactly. I use separate TcpClients for each connection, that's why it is so strange...

Comment: Please post the stack trace. I suspect that somehow you aren't using multiple TcpClient instances. The .NET framework has almost no bugs, especially after a decade of production hardening. Hard to believe you have found one with a trivial program.

Comment: thanks use! I updated my comment with it.

Comment: So the exception does not happen in TcpClient but in OnConnectCallBack. What variable was null there, exactly. Find out using the debugger. Then find out why it was null.

Comment: In OnConnectCallback there is only _tcpClient.EndConnect(ar) and _tcpClient is not null. If I move the mouse above that when code stooped by breakpoint, all of its properties are System.NullReferenceException. Its client property is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is in my oppinion a result of the multiple calls of the asynchronous method `BeginnConnect` on the same instance of TcpClient without waiting for a established connection.

Depending of the intention of your stress test you have (at least) two possibilities:

1. If you want to stress your application with multiple `TcpClients` you can create a List of `TcpClients` and iterate over this List to call `BeginConnect`. You should pass the instance of the `TcpClient` in the argument to have this instance in the callback function.
2. To stress your application with fast connects, but only one at a time, call `Connect` instead of `BeginnConnect`. This will block the thread until the connection is established. Afterwards you call directly `Close` to disconnect. As this disposes the `TcpClient` you have to create a new instace before you call `Connect` again.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code on how you're using this method (hint: post your code), it's hard to be certain of the problem.

Based on what you've explained, I'd guess that you're trying to use `TcpClient` across multiple concurrent operations. `TcpClient` doesn't support concurrent operations; you may use the `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` pairs to perform operations asynchronously, but asynchronous processing does not equal concurrent processing.

Create an instance of `TcpClient` for each concurrent operation to solve your problem. This could be easily be achieved by creating one each time your loop runs.